# Searching through subdirectories for certain file extensions

Tags: php

I am writing a program in php that is looking through a media directory for subdirectories, and if the subdirectories have at least one of a certain file with a specified file extension, then a hide/show link will be printed for the subdirectory. If the hide/show link is clicked, the links for the files with the specified extensions will appear. My code works for the most part but as soon as a subfolder is found that contains the specified file extensions and is printed, any folders found after that subfolder are printed out, whether or not they contain the files I am looking for. This results in a hide/show link being printed out that won't do anything when I click on it. I thought that maybe this had to do with failing to reset my `$content` variable, but if I use `unset()` or reset the variable to a zero, it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
foreach($files as $folder){
  //Looks for subdirectory in the wifi folder 
  //and checks for video files before proceeding
  if(sizeof( $folder ) > 0) {
    foreach (glob("../www/media/" . $folder . "/*", GLOB_BRACE) as $fileExt) {
      $fileExtLC = pathinfo( strtolower($fileExt), PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

      if($fileExtLC === "mp4" || $fileExtLC === "mov" || $fileExtLC === "3gp") {
        $content = '1';
        break;
      }
    }
    if($content === '1'){
      //print show/hide link for subdirectory here

      //Search through subdirectories in media directory for 
      //video files and print links to screen
      $direcPath2 = '../www/media/' . $folder .'/';

      $dir_handle2 = @opendir($direcPath2) or die("Unable to open " . $direcPath2);  
      while($f2 = readdir($dir_handle2)){
        $filesExten2 = pathinfo( strtolower($f2), PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        if($filesExten2 == "mov" || $filesExten2 == "mp4" || $filesExten2 == "3gp") {
          //print link to files here
        }
      }
      closedir($dir_handle2);  
    }    
  }                                                 
}
```

Comment: You need to reset `$content` to a value besides '1'. Add a line after the first `foreach` statement like this: `$content = 0;`

Comment: Thanks! I used unset($content) after the if($content === '1') section and that did the trick.